# How to load view of xib file in another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Xib File

```
@interface SearchingPropertyViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *searchingView
```

i added the below code to the button action in another ViewController

```
SearchingPropertyViewController *ps    = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchingPropertyViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:ps.searchingView];
```

I just wanted to load searchingView in another view controller

Comment: is not `[self.view addSubview:ps.searchingView];` it is `[self.view addSubview:ps.view];`, if your searchingView is loaded in SearchingPropertyViewController its automatically comes in preview

Comment: no I want to load searchingView from xib file into another view controller

Comment: `SearchingPropertyViewController *ps = [[SearchingPropertyViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchingPropertyViewController" bundle:nil]; [self.view addSubview:ps.searchingView];` ?

Comment: I did that also if you want I will mail the code. please check the code

Comment: @VickyiOS, have you tried below answer. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Simple solution :) Please find view controller loadview method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

```
         SearchingPropertyViewController *searchPVC = [[SearchingPropertyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchingPropertyViewController" bundle:nil ];
        [searchPVC loadView];
        [self.view addSubview:searchPVC.textLabel];
```

Comment: Yes Bro, I got the answer thanks for the reply @vignesh

Comment: How can I do the same thing with loading view to another view controller like modal pop up i did this but entire view controller is loading UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
HomeVC *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
[vc loadView];    [self.view addSubview:vc.searchView];